# Selecting the mic of the phone instead of the headset in Windows Phone 8.0 application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, audio, windows-phone-8, xna

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.0 application in Visual Studio 2012. There I am accessing microphone like this

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;
```

But when a headset plugged in with a in-built microphone it automatically changing the default to that mic in headset. But I want to get the input from the microphone of the phone all the time, not from the mic in headset.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible (instead of impossible word :P )

In Android for example, when you put the headphones in the jack, there's no way to let the speakers instead of the headphones.

In this scenario it's the same, but with the microphone. At least is what I think...not completly sure...

regards,

Comment: :D Thank you for the reply. There is a **Microphone.All;** method which will return a **ReadOnlyCollection**. Cannot I get a help from that ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone.all.aspx in the remarks says:"This property will always return the default microphone on Windows Phone, and it will only return one device."

Comment: thanks for the info. So why two methods **Default** and **All** ?

Comment: maybe it's work under development...preparing for the future ;)

Comment: So isn't there any other method to access microphone while the headset has connected ?